# Building a History Screen in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, timer, flutter-dependencies, history

I'm working on the History section on my Flutter Application, here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

The History section has information from my 'BUILD CONFIDENCE' section which is voice meditation screen with a Timer. How can I use the information from my 'BUILD CONFIDENCE' section to display these on the History screen?

- The days the user has listened to it in a row
- The number of sessions completed
- The overall time from the meditation sessions
- The Date when the user has listened to the meditation, taking the actions that the user has written down in the meditation session and list them out.

Comment: I guess you want state management.. Take a look at Provider package.. It is easy to integrate as well..

Comment: I'll take a look at the Provider package, thank you.